# Mock react-dom Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to mock the react-dom module using Jest

```
import React from 'react';
import {configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Link from '../components/DumbComp';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

jest.mock('react-dom');
describe('Link',() =>{
it('should render correctly', ()=>{
expect(render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  <Link title="mockTitle" url="mockUrl" />, 'element-node'
);
expect(render).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
});
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
Link › should render correctly

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [<Link title="mockTitle" url="mockUrl" />, "element-node"]
But it was not called.
```

It seems that when I mock the render method it doesn't return anything. How can I correctly mock it?

I'm using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/wehkamp-techblog/unit-testing-your-react-application-with-jest-and-enzyme-81c5545cee45), see under the "The art of mocking" section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create a manual mock create in the same file like this:

```
jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({
     render: jest.fn(),
}));
```

I would recommend to have a look at [snapshot](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html) and use it togheter with enyzme. It makes testing easier because you can write something like this:

```
describe ('Link',() =>{
  it ('should render correctly', ()=> {

    const component = mount(
      <Link title="mockTitle" url="mockUrl" />
    );

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Which gives you a snapshot of how the component got rendered exactly. You can also use it with function you test and it will give you a snapshot of all the calls your function got called with and the arguments the function got called with.

Comment: This is probably a seperate issue but when I mock react-dom, I get the following error:     TypeError: Cannot read property 'EventPluginHub' of undefined. Would you know how to solve that at all please?

Comment: I don't know what causes that error. Overall why are you testing if render has been called? What value does it give to your test if render has been called? I think you get more value out of your test if you check the result of your render with a snapshot. Because the snapshot will have more information in it than just for you to know that a render has been called. If you want I can edit my post and add a more extensive example on how to test with snapshot.

Comment: It was for a tutorial that required it.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a mock file next to your **node_modules** in `__mocks__/react-dom.js`

```
// react-dom.js
export default {
  render: jest.fn(),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer might be a little out of date. To mock `react-dom` without side-effects you need to only mock the function you need, which in this case is the `render` function.

This can be done using Jest's `requireActual` like so:

```
jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-dom'),
  render: jest.fn(),
}))
```